# How can i synchronize this code using barrier?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, synchronization

I am writing a parallel program for implementing matrix multiplication.

In the `main` function, I first created a pool of threads(=`num_threads`) and then implement the function `mult` on each of the threads. Each of these threads is responsible for computing some rows of the output matrix.

But the output obtained is not correct.

I guess it is because all the threads are not created by the time the main thread exits the for loop and frees the pool. (since the thread `pool_free` function waits for the spawned threads to finish).

If i use `sleep(1)`, it gives enough time for all the threads to be created, and the output obtained is fine but is there any way to eliminate `sleep` as I need to track the time taken for execution of this code.

```
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

int i1[num_threads];;
for(i=0;i<num_threads;i++){
    i1[i] = i;
    int err = threadpool_add_task(pool,Mult,(void *)&i1[i],1);
}

//sleep(1);

threadpool_free(pool,1);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **pthread barriers**. You can find documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/gfwek/index.html)

There are 4 steps:

1. Declare a **pthread_barrier_t barr;**
2. Call **pthread_barrier_init(&barr, NULL, NUM_THREADS)**;
3. Call **pthread_barrier_wait(&barr);** where you want to sync your threads
4. Destroy the barrier.